# iBeacon fails in iOS 8.x on Xamarin. Is this a hardware, compiler, or iOS issue?

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin, ibeacon

iOS8 requires the info.plist to have this set `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`, and the following code to enable iBeacons:

```
   // NEW REQUIRED IN iOS 8x
   locationMgr = new CLLocationManager ();
   locationMgr.RequestWhenInUseAuthorization ();
```

**Question 1**

Although the Apple web site says iBeacons are supported, it's not uncommon for certain features to disappear in more modern versions of the OS. (it already happened with an update to OSX preventing iBeacons)

Can anyone tell me if iBeacons (both broadcasting and receiving) is supported on the following devices:

- iPad Model A1455 8.x and newer
- iPad Model A1458 8.x and newer

**Question 2**

Can anyone tell me if the following code (C#, or Xamarin compiled output) is correct:

The following Xamarin C# code is supposed to broadcast an iBeacon on an iPad running 8.x, and I deployed the app, as-is to one iPad (model A1455)
https://github.com/mikebluestein/FindTheMonkey

**What I've done**

I've attempted many iBeacon demos and have no idea why the broadcast of the iBeacon seems to fail. I've created support tickets with Apple, Xamarin and am unable to locate the bug in either C# code, Xamarin to Objective C output, or the target iOS/Hardware support.

Instead of using an iPhone, I then inverted the iPad/iPhone logic (so I can detect nearby monkeys using an iPad) and deployed it to model (A1458) iPad.

I got the prompt to use iBeacons on the second iPad (as requested by the first), however it doesn't seem to detect the iBeacon from the other device.  Any assistance is appreciated, as none of the samples I've attempted, work.

Comment: Downvoter: Please explain

Comment: Although I did not downvote, I see a few problems with this question: 1) There are two questions in it. One question per question, please.  2) Questions should provide code in the question, not merely provide a link to github. Rather than asking "is this correct," it would be better to say what result you get and what you want.

Answer (score 0):

They recently changed more about how you must create an iBeacon using core bluetooth. Mike updated his repo and so did I: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/iBeaconsEverywhere

The change here is that you must:

1.) Create CBPeripheralManager and Delegate in constructor
2.) Your id's and uuid should be scoped to class level
3.) You must create your region and start advertising later on in ViewDidAppear